# How to copy numeric data from file to array in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have some data in output.txt as shown below. I wanted to copy the data from file to array in Linux. I wanted to do this by using awk.

```
3.2222196800737746e-01
9.0625504539639357e-02
-4.4309220157707685e-01
7.6522564411406657e-01
-7.1683767983542657e-01
4.8589460714063371e-01
-2.5294463208548001e-01
2.8153758928251349e-01
-1.9848560597677056e-01
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: [Google search on SO](https://www.google.com/search?as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com#q=site:stackoverflow.com+bash+array+from+file)

Comment: The important part of your question is missing - why? As stated it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this:

```
arr=($(cat output.txt))
echo ${arr[0]}
3.2222196800737746e-01

echo ${arr[2]}
-4.4309220157707685e-01
```

First data is stored in slot `0` second in slot `1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Few other ways to do the same:

```
$ ary=($(< file))
$ echo "${ary[0]}"
3.2222196800737746e-01
```

Using `bash` version 4 or later:

```
$ readarray -t ary < file
$ echo "${ary[0]}"
3.2222196800737746e-01
```

```
$ mapfile -t ary < file
$ echo "${ary[0]}"
3.2222196800737746e-01
```

Or if you insist on doing it with `awk`, then:

```
$ awk '{ary[i++]=$0}END{print ary[0]}' file
3.2222196800737746e-01
```